# Compare 2 Data frames for partial similarities

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I compare 2 data frames and remove the rows that have similar values?

```
df = pd.read_csv('trace_id.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('people.csv')
combinedf = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

[image]

df contains the column 'trace_id', and df1 contains the columns 'index' and 'name'. Notice that trace_id and index are very similar in values, 'TRACE_PERSON_0000000003' and 'PERSON_0000000003' respectively. How do I remove the rows between that have similar trace_id and index values.

Example: trace_id = 'TRACE_PERSON_0000000003' and index = 'PERSON_0000000003', both its trace_id, index and name will be removed. 'PERSON_0000000000' are not found in the trace_id column, so 'PERSON_0000000000' and 'Amy Berger' will be retained in the data frame.

Comment: Are you saying you want to skip `TRACE_PERSON_000000003` and `PERSON_000000003`?  So, your list would have persons 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, etc?  If that's the case, then you CERTAINLY don't want to concatenate them, because the indexes don't line up.

Comment: yes, i want the dataframe to have person 0,1,2,4 and their names. if not concat, how should i go about doing it?

Comment: You can create a new column ```index``` on dataframe ```df1``` - where using the ```df1.apply``` function you can remove the leading phrase "TRACE_" ... now you can use ```pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on=["index"])``` ... the next step will be to remove these rows from df1 and df2 ... If you share the samples of the dataset then I can give a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to be sure without example data, but you can:

1. delete `TRACE_` from the `trace_id` column of `df`
2. merge on the trimmed `trace_id` and `index`, passing `indicator=True` to get a merge indicator column named `_merge`
3. exclude rows where `_merge == 'both'`

```
df = pd.read_csv('trace_id.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('people.csv')

# Delete "TRACE_" from `trace_id` column
df['trace_id_trimmed'] = df['trace_id'].str.replace('TRACE_', '')

# Outer merge with indicator column
merged = df.merge(df1, 
                  how='outer', 
                  left_on='trace_id_trimmed', 
                  right_on='index', 
                  indicator=True)

# Exclude rows where merge key was found in both DataFrames
merged = merged[merged['_merge'] != 'both'].copy()
```